# How to align-center an image/figure with Hugo (go static site generator)?

Tags: hugo

I am looking for a solution that works with `hugo server` command. I am aware that I could create an additional .css file inside `static/css` directory and have it merged into the public directory with `hugo` command, however that does not work with `hugo server` unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at Hugo Pipes? or asset pipelines?

Comment: I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Hugo Pipes](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/), you have an example with "[Hugo Pipes Revolution -- A Hugo built-in asset pipeline](https://regisphilibert.com/blog/2018/07/hugo-pipes-and-asset-processing-pipeline/)" from [Regis Philibert](https://regisphilibert.com/about/) to give some examples.

> From now on, Hugo will take care of bundling, minifying, fingerprinting our assets and even compiling our sass files! All of this without any external build tools.

So it works with `hugo server`.
You can define your method in `assets`:

> These methods will only be available on files living in the `assets` directory: think of it as a `static` directory except the files will not be published by default.
>
> Much like its static counterpart:
>
> - Its location is configurable with the `assetDir` key of your `config.yaml`. (will default to `assets`)
> - It follows the Hugo’s file unison logic.
>     Meaning, anything in your `project/assets` will override homonymous files of your `theme/assets`.

From there, you can adapt one of the [sass centering techniques](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/centering-mixin/) to apply it automatically on your images using pipes.
See "[Centering With Sass](https://www.sitepoint.com/centering-with-sass/)".